# WCF Service Begin method calls Background worker

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I know information about this is spread all over internet, but I could not find any solution specific to my scenario.

I am using .NET 4.5 VS 2012

I have created a  WCF service as

```
#region ISampleService Members

public IAsyncResult BeginServiceMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);

    return new CompletedAsyncResult<String>(msg.ToUpper());
}

public string EndServiceMethod(IAsyncResult result)
{
    CompletedAsyncResult<String> res = result as CompletedAsyncResult<String>;
    return res.Data;
}

#endregion
```

Now what I need to do is call another method from **BeginServiceMethod**, which eventually starts a background worker to perform its action. On background worker completed event I want continue the execution of **EndServiceMethod**.

I don't know whether it is possible or not or whether it is a good design or not. Actually I came across this problem while migrating old code to new framework and just want to do some improvement in design as well as code.

**[EDIT]** 
In other words I can say I need to plug in my actions in between beginX and endX methods.

Comment: Usually, the  Begin and End pattern should be good enough. Why would you need an background worker? Eventually, It all depends on what the method being migrated does. if you can share some more light on what needs to be done, someone will be able to help you. Looking at the example posted in your question, I don't think its necessary to have  a background worker.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont want to host it in IIS so every request will be processed by same thread and i dont want to block the calling thread

Comment: Don't create a singleton service. have you checked WCF instance context mode? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx setting the right context mode will ensure your service is not blocked

Comment: What I need to know and understand the working of is why method are split if they are called one after another in most scenario, except in some cases I found on internet in which another service is invoked. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234085/Fixing-WCF-to-build-highly-scalable-async-REST-API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This msdn blog post should answer your question thoroughly: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/02/09/scale-wcf-application-better-with-asynchronous-programming.aspx

The above article includes sample code which should help.

The gist of the article is:

"*For best performance, here are two principles when you call/implement the above asynchronous pattern:

·        Principle 1: Do not do heavy-weighted work inside the Begin method (which is BeginDoWork above).
The reason for this is that you should return the calling thread as soon as possible so that the caller can schedule other work. If it’s a UI thread, the application needs to use the thread to respond to user inputs. You should always put heavy operations in a different thread if possible.

·        Principle 2: Avoid calling End method (which is EndDoWork above) on the same thread of the Begin method.
The End method is normally blocking. It waits for the operation to complete. If you implement the End method, you would see that it actually calls IAsyncResult.WaitHandle.WaitOne(). On the other hand, as a normal implementation (for example, the sample attached in this Blog entry), this WaitHandle is a delay allocated ManualResetEvent. As long as you don’t call it, it would be not allocated at all. For fast operations, this is pretty cheap. However, once End is called, you would have to allocate it. The right place to call End is from the callback of the operation. When the callback is invoked, it means that the blocking work is really completed. At this point, you can call End to get data retrieved without sacrificing performance.*"

Note that the above post is a bit dated, since you are using .Net 4.5 you can also use the async await pattern.

You can also start a thread by using the Task parallel Library (TPL):
Task.Factory.StartNew()... When using TPL based async operations in WCF (.net 4.0+) which is recommended over traditional Async (IasyncResult).

In case you cannot use TPL based operations you can do a BeginInvoke on a delegate which uses the same API.

Ask me if you want the details on exactly how to do the above, I didn't write those as you would find plenty of articles on the net on the same.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.